# Messed up /usr/ directory in Ubuntu. Can't sudo!

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ubuntu-11.04

In ubuntu 11.04 I seem to have messed up the permissions/ownership of the /usr/ directory. It won't let me sudo -s to fix them!

```
sudo: must be setuid root
```

and I can't login as root because I'm on ubuntu and don't know the password. Does anybody have any advise? I also can't change the boot menu for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot from a live CD and then either:

- mount the root partition and ad setuid to sudo binary

```
mount /dev/sdxx /mnt
chmod +s /mnt/usr/bin/sudo
```

- mount the root partition, chroot and change root password

```
mount /dev/sdxx /mnt
mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
chroot /mnt
passwd
```

Where `/dev/sdxx` is your root partition

Comment: Its the best answer but not quite what I wanted. Moral= always set the root password!

Comment: And/or, moral: don't mess with `/usr`.

Comment: If you have run a stray `chmod -R whatever` then the only sane way to recover is to restore from backups or reinstall your system.  Otherwise, you will be mired with lost or insecure privileges for quite some time to come.